# How can I retrieve a particular column from SQLite and display it in a ListView form in android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How can I retrieve a particular coloumn column from SQLite and display it in a ListView form in android?

Hi

I have a database having with 28 rows and 8 columns-saved in  "**assets**" folder of my project in eclipse, just for saving application data. My goal is to read one or two specific columns (not one value) from the database in "**assets**" folder and display that column's data in a ListView form.

However, I don't want to read all columns at once, because it's slow as I have blob's in db too. Instead, I'd like to read just one column at a time, separately, and display it in ListView form. Can you please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider a variation of this:

select column_name
from table_name
where
 column_name = desired_value
order by
 column_name

Comment: Can you post an example program of this for me.